# StateServer context.Session[key] not available

Tags: asp.net, stateserver

I'm a newbie to the StateServer. In one of my website, session state mode is StateServer. I have a Imagehandler in one of my component and in that i try to retrive the Session using the key - as below

```
context.Session[key]
```

but always i see that the Session.Key.Count is 0 for StateServer. But for InProc it works. Can you please advise me and throw some light on where is go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the state server running? You might need to make sure the service is started AND set to Automatic within services.msc

More info on the different [session states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) from msdn